# NPM package contains node_modules which conflicts with other packages

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, office-ui-fabric, azure-devops-extensions

I am trying to get the latest version of the [`office-ui-fabric-react` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/office-ui-fabric-react) to work with the latest version of the [`vss-web-extension-sdk` npm package](https://www.npmjs.com/package/vss-web-extension-sdk).

**global npm packages**:

```
+-- typescript@2.9.2
+-- webpack@4.12.0
```

**package.json** (dependencies only):

```
"dependencies": {
    "office-ui-fabric-react": "^6.103.0",
    "vss-web-extension-sdk": "^5.141.0"
},
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/react": "^16.7.3",
    "@types/react-dom": "^16.0.9"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "module": "amd",
        "moduleResolution": "node",
        "target": "es6",
        "lib": ["es5", "es6", "dom"],
        "jsx": "react",
        "rootDir": "src/",
        "outDir": "dist/",
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "types": [ "react", "react-dom" ]
    }
}
```

When I run `tsc -p .` I get an error that it cannot find the modules necessary:

> error TS2307: Cannot find module 'VSS/Controls/Navigation'.

If I add `"vss-web-extension-sdk"` to my tsconfig.json types, the module properly resolves, but compilation fails:

> node_modules/vss-web-extension-sdk/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3668:13
>   - error TS2717: Subsequent property declarations must have the same type.  Property 'div' must be of type
>   'DetailedHTMLProps, HTMLDivElement>',
>   but here has type 'DetailedHTMLProps,
>   HTMLDivElement>'.

It seems to me that it is failing perhaps because the @types/react found within the node_modules in vss-web-extension-sdk is conflicting with my @types/react found within my node_modules.

@types/react: `// Type definitions for React 16.7`
vss-web-extension-sdk/node_modules/@types/react: `// Type definitions for React 15.6`

I have tried to modify my tsconfig.json in numerous ways to no avail, and this is not an expert area of mine. How can I get these packages to play well with each other?

Comment: Indeed, it looks like `office-ui-fabric-react` version `6.103.0` requires React 16 while `vss-web-extension-sdk` version `5.141.0` requires React 15.  You could use an older version of `office-ui-fabric-react`, such as `5.131.1`, which is compatible with React 15, and then be sure to specify a `15.x.x` version of `@types/react` in your `package.json`.  I don't know if this is the best solution.

Comment: I'm constantly running into similar issues and they are currently the bane of my existence.  If I'd known using vss-web-extension-sdk and TypeScript would lead to this version hell, I would have chosen a different career path.  I have no desire to spend most of my days sifting through changelogs, dependencies and source code trying to figure out which version of X crappy software is compatible with which version of Y crappy software.